# Hash string with SHA256 key

Tags: c#, hash, sha256

I can't get the correct HASH and I really have no idea what is wrong with it.
All hashes I get aren't correct as on this site: http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator

```
public NavigatedPage ()
{
    string bytes = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Command>  <LMI_PAYMENT_NO>1000</LMI_PAYMENT_NO><LMI_MERCHANT_ID>2096</LMI_MERCHANT_ID>  <LMI_HASH></LMI_HASH>  <LMI_PAYMENT_SYSTEM>18</LMI_PAYMENT_SYSTEM>  <LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT>1001</LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT>  <LMI_PAYMENT_DESC>Оплата договора</LMI_PAYMENT_DESC></Command>";
    string key = "14653285";
    string message = bytes;//xml document in a string
    
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    
    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
    
    HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);
    
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    
    byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    
    var tempHash = ByteToString(hashmessage);
}

public static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
{
    string sbinary = "";

    for ( int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++ )
    {
        sbinary += buff[ i ].ToString("X2"); // hex format
    }
    return ( sbinary );
}
```

That's what i've done, but it gives me wrong result.

Comment: Obviously, you are new to StackOverflow, but could you post more acceptable code? What is `ShaKey`? How come those other lines are not in a function? Just post the whole thing

Comment: Also text/a password is not a proper key. Either use a key consisting of 16 to 32 random bytes or use password based KDF to derive it from the password. (I recommend random keys over passwords, whenever possible)

Comment: The whole thing is much larger.

Comment: I need to hash it with secret key from server, where i'll send this document later. So there shouldn't be random key.

Comment: Works for me. I get `0cfaff5ec263...` as result from both the site you linked and your program. (As long as I paste the proper string without the escape sequences on the site)

Comment: Have you used secret key in program and on that site?
My knowledges in english aren't so good, sorry)

Comment: Works. The hashes from your program and the site are identical. I think @CodesInChaos nails the problem: "as long as I paste **the proper string without the escape sequences** on the site"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put your string into the `Text you want to convert to a SHA-256 hash:` textbox on the site you linked, you have to remove the c# escape characters for your string (in this case replace `\"` with `"`) then you get the same result - your code works.

This is because C# will see `\"` as an escaped `"` and the site will not (therefore including it in the hash)

[Your Result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Umtpmg)

[Their Result](http://www.online-convert.com/result/2295cd39d9803ea4cddbf2a1d6bc3859)